# How to get time from equation of linear uniformly accelerated motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time, acceleration

I have had a problem solving this equation for time (from Linear Uniformly Accelerated Motion (LUAM)):

$$ s= v_0t + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 $$

I'll appreciate if someone could provide me some step-by-step solution to this.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. Are you trying to invert the equation to $t$ = *something*? If so, rewrite it as $\tfrac{1}{2}at^2 + v_0t - s = 0$, so it's a quadratic in $t$, then just use the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

Comment: yup, that's pretty much I wanted to do, but somehow I missed the quadratic stuff in there. I'll try to solve it this way, thank you very much for help :) you should post it as answer so I can approve you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. You see that it's a quadratic equation in $t$.

$$
0= -s + v_0t + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2
$$

Solve for t.
$$
t=\frac{-v_{0}\pm \sqrt{v_{0}^2-4(\frac{1}{2}a)(-s)}}{a}
$$

The [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) tells you should get exactly two solutions to the equation.  Chose the $t$ that is most likely to make sense